# Node.js: Async callback in _.chain underscore

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, underscore.js

The `arr.length` is still undefined after I call `_.chain()` underscore operation:

```
var arr = _.chain(msg)
   .groupBy(function(item) {return item.ts_simple; })
   .value();

console.log(arr.length); //undefined
console.log(arr); //correct object array
```

The first `console.log(arr.length)` for underscore `var` array length is `undefined` while the `console.log(arr)` outputs the correct returned object array.

How do I callback after underscore operation is complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groupBy()` [returns](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) an object, not an array.

It has no `length` property.